# Vim duplicate with same cursor position

Tags: vim

I want to duplicate a line with Vim. Every time when I use `yyp` or any other command, I have to jump the cursor to the position where it was. Is there any trick to duplicate a line and jump the cursor to its position, like maybe using a macro to save current the cursor position, duplicate, and then jump to the required position?

Comment: Which os linux/mac?

Comment: @minigeek linux/ubuntu

Comment: First clear me this thing : you want to paste say for eg. `hi there` and cursor to be at the end right? But by default cursor is at beginning of `hi there`.

Comment: @minigeek if the cursor is at letter 't' (first of the word 'there') and I clicked yyp, the line will be duplicated, and the cursor will be at the start of the new line, I want the cursor at the letter 't' of the new created line..

Comment: @minigeek I tried using a macro: and it's like that, qm, :let line = line('.')<cr> :let col = col('.')<cr> yyp :call cursor(line, col) then click @m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I'd see to do what you want, given you only use it for `yyp` (i.e. copy currentline and paste it below), is to record in a macro:

```
mmyyp`mj
```

what that does is:

- to record a mark `m`,
- copy current line
- paste it
- jump to col+row location of the mark `m`
- move the cursor one line down

ideally what you'd want is a jump to a column, not changing the row. I'm not sure if it's possible, I never needed that before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `ctrl-o` and `ctrl-i` to jump back and forth.